# How to set up style for all tables in symfony 3 Bootstrap 3/4 twig

Tags: css, twig, symfony, bootstrap-4

I want to have the same look for all tables and don't set it every time. 
My view:

```
{% extends 'MyBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block pageTitle %}
 Info Table {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}


{% block pageContainer %}
<h1>My Info Table</h1>


<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>parentid</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entry in rows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entry.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.productName }} &#10063; {{ entry.sortName }}</td>
            <td>{{ entry.parentId }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">You don't have this!</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

The Bootstrap has defined in 'MyBundle::base.html.twig'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="EN">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% spaceless %}{% block pageTitle %} - TEST {% endblock %}{% endspaceless %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/main.css') }}"/>
    {% endblock %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('dtf-3.ico') }}"/>
</head>
<body>
{% block header %}
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">    
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="{{ path('MY_home') }}">TEST_menu</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{{ path('TEST_infoTable') }}">Info Table</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashBag.get('msg') %}
    <div> {{ flashMessage }}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% block pageContainer %}{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

I have configured the style for all forms and it works fine using Bootstarp 3/4. 
For customization I've created *form_theme.html.twig* and setup in *config.yml*

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
         - 'MyBundle:Form:form_theme.html.twig'
         - 'MyBundle:Form:table_theme.html.twig'
```

MyBundle:Form:form_theme.html.twig:

```
{%- block form_start -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set method = method|upper %}
        {%- if method in ["GET", "POST"] -%}
            {% set form_method = method %}
        {%- else -%}
            {% set form_method = "POST" %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('form-horizontal'))|trim }) %}
        <form
        name="{{ name }}" method="{{ form_method|lower }}"{% if action != '' %} action="{{ action }}"{% endif %}{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
        {%- if form_method != method -%}
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}"/>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock form_start -%}

{% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-group  row{{ errors|length > 0 ? ' has-error':'' }}">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            <div class="col-10">
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}

{# Labels #}

{%- block form_label -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if label is not same as(false) -%}
            {% if not compound -%}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
            {%- endif -%}
            {% if required -%}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
            {%- endif -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' col-sm-2 col-form-label')|trim }) %}
            {% if label is empty -%}
                {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                    {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                    }) %}
                {%- else -%}
                    {% set label = name|humanize %}
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endif -%}
            <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock form_label -%}

{# Widgets #}

{%- block form_widget_simple -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {%- set type = type|default('text') -%}
        {% if type != 'file' %}
            {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim }) %}
        {% endif %}
        <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock form_widget_simple -%}

{%- block textarea_widget -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim }) %}
        <textarea {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>{{ value }}</textarea>
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock textarea_widget -%}

{%- block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {%- if required and placeholder is none and not placeholder_in_choices and not multiple and (attr.size is not defined or attr.size <= 1) -%}
            {% set required = false %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim }) %}
        <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
            {%- if placeholder is not none -%}
                <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ placeholder != '' ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ? placeholder : placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain)) }}</option>
            {%- endif -%}
            {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
                {% set options = preferred_choices %}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
                {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                    <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endif -%}
            {%- set options = choices -%}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
        </select>
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed -%}

{%- block choice_widget_expanded -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {%- for child in form %}
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    {{- form_widget(child) -}}
                    {{- form_label(child, null, {translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) -}}
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor -%}
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded -%}

{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for error in errors %}
            <span class="help-block">{{ error.message }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}

{% block button_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock button_row %}

{%- block button_widget -%}
    {%- if label is empty -%}
        {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
            {% set label = label_format|replace({
            '%name%': name,
            '%id%': id,
            }) %}
        {%- else -%}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' btn')|trim }) %}
    <button type="{{ type|default('button') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</button>
{%- endblock button_widget -%}

{% block submit_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set type = type|default('submit') %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('btn btn-primary'))|trim }) %}
        {{ block('button_widget') }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock submit_widget %}
```

I tray do it the same way for table, but in fields (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form):

- bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig
- bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
- form_div_layout.html.twig
- form_table_layout.html.twig
- foundation_5_layout.html.twig

I don't find the tables tags for set up: thead, cellpadding.

How do I have the same layout for all tables in Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the the solution.

Crete the main.css file and I copy and change same line from bootstrap.css .

For example to decrease cellpadding form default (padding: 0.35rem;) I've added in main.css

```
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.35rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #eceeef;
}
```

and  main.css must be put after bootstrap.css

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create a new block in `base.html.twig`?

```
{℅ block pageContainer ℅}
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        {℅ block table ℅}{℅ endblock ℅}
    </table>
{℅ endblock ℅}
```

Then, each time you want the same table style for your tables, but a different content obviously, just override the table block.

```
{℅ block table ℅}
   <thead class="thead-inverse">...</thead>
   <tbody>...</tbody>
{℅ endblock ℅}
```

Comment: It does not solve the whole problem, but thanks for suggest this :-)

Comment: I want change padding for records and for same views I don't use  base.html.twig. On same page I have more then one table and text

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the table bundle at https://tablebundle.org ;)